# xlc: not found on aix 6.1

Tags: unix, aix, xlc

On  install path of websphere MQ/java/lib/jdbc>make oracle
I am getting below error

```
xlc: not found
```

I am not sure if xlc is installed in my machine. My machine is AIX 6.1. But I can find xlcpp in my machine. how to proceed?Is there any way to create switch file?

If I execute `$ /usr/ccs/lib/cpp -help`

I am getting

```
1506-173 (W) Option help is not valid. Enter xlc for list of valid options.
```

how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/usr/ccs/lib/cpp is not the XL C/C++ for AIX compiler, it is the C Pre-Processor which ships as part of AIX. The XL C/C++ for AIX compiler is a separate Licensed Program Product for which licenses must be separately purchased.

If you have XL C/C++ for AIX installed, you would find the /usr/vac/bin/xlc and /usr/vacpp/bin/xlc++ commands installed on your system.  You can also check for the filesets vac.C and vacpp.cmp.core using the lslpp command:

lslpp -L vac.C vacpp.cmp.core

Answer (score 0):

Dwayne has it mostly right but I believe xlc++ also has a version of xlc.  I see in your other question that you have xlcpp so perhaps what you need to do is add /usr/vacpp/bin to your PATH.

I also tend to use grep with lslpp:

```
lslpp -ch | grep vac
```

should tell you which xlc, xlcpp, etc you have installed.

HTH